# Assign Results from query to variable for use in case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, analytics

I am trying to take the avg of a total sample column and compare to the column value off each specific record.

I have done this in SQL Server by declaring a variable and then setting it to the results of a query.

I am trying to do the same thing in PG, but I am not having any success.

In the below sample, `myconstant2` works because of the hard coded value but `myconstant` does not because the value is set to the single row query result.

Any pointers here?

```
with myconstant (var1) as 
(
    values (select AVG(ptb_account_score_c) 
            from salesforce_production.accounts)
),
myconstant2 (var2) as 
(
     values(6)
)
select
    Id,
    ptb_account_score_c,
    var1,
    var2,
    case 
       when ptb_account_score_c > var1 then 1 else 0 
    end as Blah
from
    salesforce_production.accounts, myconstant, myconstant2
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a window function:

```
select a.*,
       (case when ptb_account_score_c > avg(a.ptb_account_score_c) over () then 1 else 0 end) as Blah
from salesforce_production.accounts a;
```

If you wanted, you could combine these into a single CTE:

```
with params as (
    select AVG(ptb_account_score_c) as var1, 6 as var2
    from salesforce_production.accounts
   )
select a.id, a.ptb_account_score_c,
       params.var1, params.var2,
       (case when a.ptb_account_score_c > params.var1 then 1 else 0 end) as Blah
from salesforce_production.accounts a cross join
     params;
```

Comment: the params CTE is what I was looking for. Guess I am a dummy and didnt realize the cross join would get me what I wanted. THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `values`:

```
WITH
       myconstant1 as (select AVG(ptb_account_score_c) as val from salesforce_production.accounts),
       myconstant2 as (select 6 as val)
SELECT Id, ptb_account_score_c, myconstant1.val,
       myconstant2.val,
       case when ptb_account_score_c > myconstant1.val then 1 else 0 end as Blah
  FROM salesforce_production.accounts,myconstant1,myconstant2
```

Comment: The second `values` is perfectly valid `select 6 as var2` can indeed be written as `values (6)`

Comment: myconstant1.val and myconstant2.val are columns not tables. What are they doing in the FROM clause?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my comment was about: `FROM salesforce_production.accounts,myconstant1.val,myconstant2.val` which was the code before it was edited.